# Ayuda como le puedo hacer para que a la hora de decir si en el codigo el numero 1 sea el resultado anterior

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Calculadora_WOG{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double res = 0;
        String operacion;
        boolean comprobar = false;

        do{
            String numero1;
            do {
                System.out.println("\n Por favor, dame el primer número de la operación. ");
                numero1 = sc.nextLine();
            } while (!numero1.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
            double nume1 = Double.parseDouble(numero1);
            double n1 = new Double(numero1);

            do {
                System.out.println("\n ¿Que operación desea hacer? (Solo coloque un signo)");
                System.out.println("Teniendo en cuenta que: \n + = sumar \n - = restar \n"
                        + " x = multiplicar \n / = dividir \n * = elevar primer número al segundo numero."
                        + "\n % = residuo");
            operacion = sc.nextLine();
                if (operacion.equals("+") || operacion.equals("-") || operacion.equals("x") ||
                    operacion.equals("X") || operacion.equals("/") || operacion.equals("%") ||
                    operacion.equals("*")) {
                    comprobar = true;
                }else { comprobar = false; }
            } while (comprobar != true);

            String numero2;
            do {
                System.out.println("\n Por favor, dame el segundo número.");
                numero2 = sc.nextLine();
            } while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
            double nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
            double n2 = new Double(numero2);

            do{
                comprobar = true;
                switch(operacion){
                    case "+":
                        res = n1 + n2;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        res = n1 - n2;
                        break;
                    case "x":
                    case "X":
                        res = n1 * n2;
                        break;
                    case "/":

                        while(n2 == 0){
                                 do {
                                    System.err.println(" En el denominador se encuentra \n"
                                            + "un cero, para evitar errores coloca otro número.");
                                    numero2 = sc.nextLine();
                                }while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
                                    nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
                                    n2 = new Double(numero2);
                        }
                        res = n1 / n2;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        res = Math.pow(n1, n2);
                        break;
                    case "%":
                        while(n2 == 0){
                                 do {
                                    System.err.println(" En el denominador se encuentra \n"
                                            + "un cero, para evitar errores coloca otro número.");
                                    numero2 = sc.nextLine();
                                }while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
                                    nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
                                    n2 = new Double(numero2);
                        }
                        res = n1 % n2;
                        break;
                }
            }while(comprobar != true);

            System.out.println("(" + numero1 + ") " + operacion + " (" + numero2 + ")" + " = " + res);
            System.out.println("\n ¿Desea hacer alguna otra operación? \n");
            System.out.println(" [s/n]");
            do{
                comprobar = true;
                operacion = sc.nextLine();

                switch (operacion) {
                    case "s":
                    case "S":
                    case "n":
                    case "N":
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.err.println("\n Error, ponga un literal valido. \n");
                        comprobar = false;
                }
            }while(comprobar != true);
        }while(operacion.equals("s") || operacion.equals("S"));
  }
}
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta, ¿puedes contextualizarla más?

Comment: puedes crear un atributo estático que sea el resultado anterior y luego llamarlo al pulsar 1, de todas formas tu código no es nada eficiente, anidar bucles consume mucha memoria, saludos

Answer (score 0):

!Buenas!

Me he tomado la molestia de rehacerte el código para que sea mucho mas legible y te he comentado las partes para que puedas entender que hace cada cosa.

Lo he ajustado a lo que tenias escrito y esta todo desde el main. **Y he resuelto tu problema**, el de guardar el valor de la operación anterior y dárselo a numero 1.

Te dejo el código, échale un vistazo:

```
//DEFINIR VARIABLES Y LAS INICIALIZO PARA AHORRAR PROBLEMAS DESPUES.

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcionUsuario;
    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    double resultadoAnterior = 0, resul = 0; //USARE resultadoAnterior COMO UNA VARIABLE AUXILIAR.
    String repetir = "";

    //-------------------------
    //MOSTRAR UN MENU PARA EL USUARIO:

    do {
    System.out.println("**CALCULADORA** \n");
    System.out.println("1. Sumar.");
    System.out.println("2. Restar.");
    System.out.println("3. Dividir.");
    System.out.println("4. Multiplicar");
    System.out.println("5. Elevar numero \n");
    System.out.print("Indica una opcion (Con numero): ");

    //OBTENER DEL USUARIO LA OPCION ELEGIDA.
    opcionUsuario = sc.nextInt();

    //PEDIR A USUARIO LOS NUMEROS A CALCULAR:
    //CON ESTE CONDICIONAL VERIFICAMOS SI EL USUARIO HA ESCRITO UNA S( SI) PARA REMPLAZAR EL VALOR DE NUM1 POR EL RESULTADO ANTERIOR
    //EN CASO DE NO REPETIR EL PROGRAMA, VOLVERA A LA NORMALIDAD.

    if(repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("N") || repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

        System.out.print("Introduce el primer valor: ");
        num1 = sc.nextDouble();

    }else if(repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {

        num1 = resultadoAnterior;
    }

    //---------------------------------


    System.out.print("Introduce el segundo valor: ");
    num2 = sc.nextDouble();

    //VERIFICAR QUE LA DIVISION NO SEA CERO:

    while(opcionUsuario == 3 && (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0)) {  // SI LA OPCION ES DIVIDIR Y CUALQUIERA DE AMBOS NUMEROS ES CERO, EMPIEZA BUCLE

        System.out.println("Error. No se puede dividir entre cero. \n");
        System.out.print("Introduce de nuevo el primer valor: ");
        num1 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Introduce de nuevo el segundo valor: ");
        num2 = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    //------------------------------------------


    //SWITCH CASE PARA LA OPCION ELEGIDA EN EL MENU

    switch(opcionUsuario) {

    case 1:
        resul = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("La suma es: " + resul);
        break;

    case 2:
        resul = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("La resta es: " + resul);
        break;

    case 3:
        resul = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println("La division es: " + resul);
        break;

    case 4:
        resul = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println("La multiplicacion es: " + resul);
        break;

    case 5:
        resul = Math.pow(num1, num2);
        System.out.println("La elevacion es: " + resul);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("La opcion no es valida.");
    }

    sc.nextLine(); //LIMPIEZA DE BUFFER

    System.out.println("¿Volver a calcular? S/N: ");  //PEDIMOS AL USUARIO SI VOLVER A REPETIR O NO.
    repetir = sc.nextLine();

    resultadoAnterior = resul; // GUARDO EL RESULTADO OBTENIDO EN UNA VARIABLE AXULIAR.

    }while(repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
```

Espero que te sirva. !Un saludo!

Comment: Si te resolvió tu problema, por favor marca como respondida la pregunta :D